# /Differences dictionary for encode parsing issue in PDF

Tags: pdf, embedded-fonts

Type1 font `/Differences` encoding uses strings in mapping of values for example 1 character is encoded to 'one'. It is used for numbers and special characters only.

What is the standard way to use these encoding?

How should I decode string from PDF which uses such encoding?

Link for the file: http://www.filedropper.com/open

Comment: Basically above document uses PDFLATEX.
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33476/why-cant-fi-be-separated-when-being-copied-from-a-compiled-pdf
so all combinations such as fi,fl,ffl etc. will be mapped to their corresponding glyphs.
How can I figure out PDF uses such encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the `/Differences` array in your file (and honestly, you should have just posted this and not a link a skeevy download page):

```
/Differences [
    24 /breve/caron/circumflex/dotaccent/hungarumlaut/ogonek/ring/tilde
    39 /quotesingle
    96 /grave
    128 /bullet/dagger/daggerdbl/ellipsis...
]
```

The way this works is that the font also has an encoding associated with it (for example `/MacRoman` or `/WinANSI`). In the case of a Type 1 font, there is an encoding built into the font. Then given a copy of that encoding, you apply the differences to it. Start from the number (your first is 24), you change entries 24-31 inclusive to `/breve`, `/circumflex` and so on.

In Type 1 fonts, there is a dictionary called `/CharStrings`, which an association of a name of a glyph with the data/code that will render it. If, for example, you get a character with code 26, you look it up in your encoding array (which should be a 256 element array for Type 1 fonts) and with the differences applied, you get the name `/circumflex`. You then look that up in the `CharStrings` dictionary, pull out the glyph data and render it. Any character that does not exist in the encoding should be set to `/.notdef` which will then render an shape representing an undefined character (usually an empty box).

Now likely your problem is, how do I turn these glyph names in something that is more useful like, say Unicode?

If you look in Annex D, you'll see a set of tables that define the character sets for standard Latin encodings. You would make a lookup table that maps Adobe standard names to Unicode. Unfortunately, the tables in Annex D are incomplete. Fortunately, Adobe has a file that defines all of that for you [here](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/opentype/glyphlist.txt). There is a link in that file which is now dead, but most likely it was meant to go [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/font.html).

Comment: *Here's the `/Differences` array in your file* - Actually there are multiple **Differences** arrays in the file. The one you show merely is the only one not packed into an object stream.

Comment: I am facing another problem in this.
The thing is I want to use '/fi' name as it is because that mapping is used in representation of word 'file' in above PDF but when I use Adobe's standard glyph list it is again converted back to some unicode given in that mapping, but I want to use for numeric, punctuational and non-ascii characters.
My question is how do I decide when to use these standard mappings provided by Adobe and when not to use them.

Comment: If a standard encoding doesn't do what you want, create a /Differences with characters that you do want and track them in your code. If you want the fi ligature, put it somewhere that is convenient.

Comment: Basically this pdf is LaTex PDF which uses the above encoding.
How can figure out if the pdf use such encoding?

Answer (score 3):

> How should I decode string from PDF which uses such encoding?

As the specification explains:

> **9.10.2 Mapping Character Codes to Unicode Values**
>
> A conforming reader can use these methods, in the priority given, to map a character code to a Unicode value. Tagged PDF documents, in particular, shall provide at least one of these methods:
>
> - If the font dictionary contains a **ToUnicode** CMap, use that CMap to convert the character code to Unicode.
> - If the font is a simple font that uses one of the predefined encodings **MacRomanEncoding**, **MacExpertEncoding**, or **WinAnsiEncoding**, or that has an encoding whose **Differences** array includes only character names taken from the Adobe standard Latin character set and the set of named characters in the Symbol font:
>
>   a) Map the character code to a character name according to Table D.1 and the font’s **Differences** array.
>
>   b) Look up the character name in the Adobe Glyph List to obtain the corresponding Unicode value.
> - If the font is a composite font ... *(not applicable in your case)*
>
> If these methods fail to produce a Unicode value, there is no way to determine what the character code represents in which case a conforming reader may choose a character code of their choosing.
>
> *(ISO 32000-1)*

First of all, therefore, you should look for a **ToUnicode** map.

If there is none (as in case of your sample document), use the **Encoding** (predefined or differences).

And if your code is not mapped to something proper in the encoding, there according to the spec *is no way to determine what the character code represents*!

If the font in question is embedded, you might yet have a way out by parsing the embedded font program which may include its own mapping to Unicode.

Otherwise, though, this is where you can start guessing (or delegate to OCR).

---

But your assumption

> It is used for numbers and special characters only.

already is wrong. If you look at your sample document, e.g. the two fonts **F25** and **F26** used on the first page of your document have a **Differences** array like this:

> 0
>   /.notdef
>   1
>   /dotaccent
>   /fi
>   /fl
>   /fraction
>   /hungarumlaut
>   /Lslash
>   /lslash
>   /ogonek
>   /ring
>   10
>   /.notdef
>   11
>   /breve
>   /minus
>   13
>   /.notdef
>   14
>   /Zcaron
>   /zcaron
>   /caron
>   /dotlessi
>   /dotlessj
>   /ff
>   /ffi
>   /ffl
>   22
>   /.notdef
>   30
>   /grave
>   /quotesingle
>   /space
>   /exclam
>   /quotedbl
>   /numbersign
>   /dollar
>   /percent
>   /ampersand
>   /quoteright
>   /parenleft
>   /parenright
>   /asterisk
>   /plus
>   /comma
>   /hyphen
>   /period
>   /slash
>   /zero
>   /one
>   /two
>   /three
>   /four
>   /five
>   /six
>   /seven
>   /eight
>   /nine
>   /colon
>   /semicolon
>   /less
>   /equal
>   /greater
>   /question
>   /at
>   /A
>   /B
>   /C
>   /D
>   /E
>   /F
>   /G
>   /H
>   /I
>   /J
>   /K
>   /L
>   /M
>   /N
>   /O
>   /P
>   /Q
>   /R
>   /S
>   /T
>   /U
>   /V
>   /W
>   /X
>   /Y
>   /Z
>   /bracketleft
>   /backslash
>   /bracketright
>   /asciicircum
>   /underscore
>   /quoteleft
>   /a
>   /b
>   /c
>   /d
>   /e
>   /f
>   /g
>   /h
>   /i
>   /j
>   /k
>   /l
>   /m
>   /n
>   /o
>   /p
>   /q
>   /r
>   /s
>   /t
>   /u
>   /v
>   /w
>   /x
>   /y
>   /z
>   /braceleft
>   /bar
>   /braceright
>   /asciitilde
>   127
>   /.notdef
>   130
>   /quotesinglbase
>   /florin
>   /quotedblbase
>   /ellipsis
>   /dagger
>   /daggerdbl
>   /circumflex
>   /perthousand
>   /Scaron
>   /guilsinglleft
>   /OE
>   141
>   /.notdef
>   147
>   /quotedblleft
>   /quotedblright
>   /bullet
>   /endash
>   /emdash
>   /tilde
>   /trademark
>   /scaron
>   /guilsinglright
>   /oe
>   157
>   /.notdef
>   159
>   /Ydieresis
>   160
>   /.notdef
>   161
>   /exclamdown
>   /cent
>   /sterling
>   /currency
>   /yen
>   /brokenbar
>   /section
>   /dieresis
>   /copyright
>   /ordfeminine
>   /guillemotleft
>   /logicalnot
>   /hyphen
>   /registered
>   /macron
>   /degree
>   /plusminus
>   /twosuperior
>   /threesuperior
>   /acute
>   /mu
>   /paragraph
>   /periodcentered
>   /cedilla
>   /onesuperior
>   /ordmasculine
>   /guillemotright
>   /onequarter
>   /onehalf
>   /threequarters
>   /questiondown
>   /Agrave
>   /Aacute
>   /Acircumflex
>   /Atilde
>   /Adieresis
>   /Aring
>   /AE
>   /Ccedilla
>   /Egrave
>   /Eacute
>   /Ecircumflex
>   /Edieresis
>   /Igrave
>   /Iacute
>   /Icircumflex
>   /Idieresis
>   /Eth
>   /Ntilde
>   /Ograve
>   /Oacute
>   /Ocircumflex
>   /Otilde
>   /Odieresis
>   /multiply
>   /Oslash
>   /Ugrave
>   /Uacute
>   /Ucircumflex
>   /Udieresis
>   /Yacute
>   /Thorn
>   /germandbls
>   /agrave
>   /aacute
>   /acircumflex
>   /atilde
>   /adieresis
>   /aring
>   /ae
>   /ccedilla
>   /egrave
>   /eacute
>   /ecircumflex
>   /edieresis
>   /igrave
>   /iacute
>   /icircumflex
>   /idieresis
>   /eth
>   /ntilde
>   /ograve
>   /oacute
>   /ocircumflex
>   /otilde
>   /odieresis
>   /divide
>   /oslash
>   /ugrave
>   /uacute
>   /ucircumflex
>   /udieresis
>   /yacute
>   /thorn
>   /ydieresis

which contains mappings for normal uppercase **/A**..**/Z** and lowercase **/a**..**/z** characters, too.

---

By the way,

> Type1 font /Differences encoding uses strings in mapping of values for example 1 character is encoded to 'one'.

is not strictly correct, the '**/**' characters are part of the respective mapped value, e.g. **/one**, and as PDF objects these are not **Strings** but **Names**.